# LocalDateTime : converting String to HH:mm:ss

Tags: java, datetime, localtime

**What I need to do :**
I need to pass a LocalDateTime object to a constructor and I have a string that have "18:14:00" as value.

**My question :**
How can I convert the string to LocalDateTime ?

**What I have done :**
After some researches, I put this but it didn't work :

```
LocalDateTime.parse("18:14:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
```

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '18:14:00' could not be
>   parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO
>   resolved to 18:14 of type java.time.format.Parsed

Comment: *didn't work* is not an error description. Do you get a wrong output or an exception?

Comment: @Jens I will be more precise next time, I got an exception : java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '18:14:00' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 18:14 of type java.time.format.Parsed

Comment: *"Unable to obtain LocalDateTime"* is because the parsed text only has time values, no date values, so it is impossible to construct a Local***Date***Time object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *"Unable to obtain LocalDateTime"* exception is because the parsed text only has *time* values, no *date* values, so it is impossible to construct a Local​***Date***​Time object.

Parse to a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) instead:

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("18:14:00");

System.out.println(dateTime); // Prints: 18:14
```

The `"HH:mm:ss"` pattern is the default for a `LocalTime`, so there is no need to specify it (see: [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_TIME)).

If you want/need a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) object, parsed similarly to how [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) did it, i.e. defaulting the Jan 1, 1970, then you need to explicitly specify the default date value:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.EPOCH_DAY, 0)
        .toFormatter();
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("18:14:00", fmt);

System.out.println(dateTime); // Prints: 1970-01-01T18:14
```

For comparison, that is equivalent to the old `SimpleDateFormat` result:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse("18:14:00");

System.out.println(date); // Prints: Thu Jan 01 18:14:00 EST 1970
```

Comment: Beautiful answer covering different options, thank you. In the latter case I think I’d do `LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalTime.parse("18:14:00").atDay(LocalDate.EPOCH);` (not sure when `LocalDate.EPOCH` was introduced, possibly Java 9).

Answer (score 4):

You have a time component, not a date component. So the best you can do (with what you have) is use a `LocalTime` (instead of a `LocalDateTime`). Like,

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse("18:14:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: And you don't even need to pass the second argument.